# Grid system in html in forloop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I'm trying to create a site for fun and I've now come across a design problem. What I'm trying to do here is to have a searchbar (that autosuggests with result from api and then the user should be able to click on image to select it).

I haven't added the autocomplete yet but what I want to do now is to make the suggestions after buttonpress present pretty. The grid comes of either in a long row or a mess of images which also ruins the layout of my other sections on the page.

Can I get some advise on how to be able to make the search results appear in a grid and work be selectable?

A part of my html:

```
    <div>
<h1>Search field</h1>
<input id="search" style="width: 500px; height: 50px;font-size:18pt;" placeholder="Titel"><br>
<button id="button" type="button">GO</button>
<div id="results"></div>
<p></p>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/seekBook.js"></script>
<script>
function selectFunction() {
return "<p1>worked</p>";
}
document.getElementById("foradd").addEventListener('click', myFunction,false)
</script>
</div>
```

my attempt in organising the grid in seekBook.js below:

```
success: function(data){
        for (i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            results.innerHTML += 
            '<div class="container">'
                +'<div class="row">'
                    +'<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">'
                        +'<hr class="marginbot-50">'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
                +'<div class="row">'
                    +'<div class="col-md-3">'
                        +'<div class="wow bounceInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">'
                            +'<div class="team boxed-grey">'
                                +'<div class="inner">'
                                    +'<h5>'
            +data.items[i].volumeInfo.title
                                    +'</h5>'
                                    +'<p class="subtitle">'
            +data.items[i].volumeInfo.authors
                                    +'</p>'
                                    +'<div class="avatar">'
                                        +'<img id="forAdd" img src="'
            +data.items[i].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail+' " onclick="selectFunction()" alt=""/>'
                                    +'</div>'
                                +'</div>'
                            +'</div>'
                        +'</div>'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
            +'</div>'
        }
    },
```

Comment: My advice: get rid of js and prepare a html only example layout. When you have the correct markup you can add js to replace multiple elements with for loop. If you can provide a jsfiddle for your problem it would be great.

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is. Please take a few minutes to read [ask] then edit question with specific problem details